# Autoform Update : "vc.resetValidation is not a function"

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm on

```
aldeed:collection2-core
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:schema-deny
npm simpl-schema
```

I get the error `vc.resetValidation is not a function` when I update a form on the user schema.
The form is effectively submitted - the update is well made.
How can I fix this error ?

Here is my query

```
{{#autoForm collection='Meteor.users' doc=currentUser type='update' id='accountForm'}}
{{> afFieldInput name='profile.phone'}}
{{> afFieldInput name='profile.avatar'}}
<button type='submit' class="at-btn dark">Update</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Here is the part of the autoform code where I think there is a validation issue

```
/// Reset array counts                                                                                              
arrayTracker.resetForm(formId);                                                                                                                                                                                                       var vc = AutoForm.getValidationContext(formId);                                                                    
if (vc) {                                                                                                          
  vc.resetValidation();                                                                                            
  // If simpleSchema is undefined, we haven't yet rendered the form, and therefore
  // there is no need to reset validation for it. No error need be thrown.
}                                                                                                                  
if (this.doc) {                                                                                                    
  event.preventDefault();                                                                                          
  AutoForm._forceResetFormValues(formId);                                                                          
}
```

Comment: If you're just wanting to reset the form's validation messages, why not just reset the form from within the ```onDestroyed``` method instead?

Comment: @blueren Tried on your advice`Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed(function () {
  AutoForm.resetForm("form-id");
});` No change, the error is still here. Did you mean that ?

Comment: Are you navigating away from the current template once the form is submitted? I mean, is ```Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed``` being called post form submission?

Comment: @blueren No, I don't navigate away from the current template once the form is submitted. Sorry, may be stupid, but do you mean like calling `onDestoyed` in a `onSubmit` `AutoForm.hooks` ?

Comment: Nope. ```onDestroyed``` is called when a template gets destroyed (when you navigate away from that template.) You might as well call ```resetForm``` from ```onSubmit``` or in fact from ```onSuccess``` hooks. ```AutoForm.addHooks(['form_id'], {
    onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
        this.resetForm()
    }
})```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `resetForm` from `onSubmit` or in fact from `onSuccess` hooks.

```
AutoForm.addHooks(['form_id'], { 
     onSuccess: function(formType, result) { 
         this.resetForm() 
     } 
}) ;
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks)

Comment: Sadly, the error is still here after `AutoForm.addHooks(['accountForm'], { 
     onSuccess: function(formType, result) { 
         this.resetForm() 
     } 
}) ;`

Comment: Can you get me a screenshot of your exact error? And where are you defining ```vc```? Also, out of curiosity, is there a specific reason you're using npm version of aldeed's packages for meteor and not the default meteor packages?

Comment: The exact error on screenshot: https://snag.gy/p3mQ8L.jpg I'm not defining vc anywhere... I'm using the nmp version of aldeed's simple schema, cause aldeed:collection2 is depreciated and the udpate to aldeed:collection2-core need this nmp version (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#important-note-the-version-in-this-repo-is-deprecated)

Comment: @Ontokrat i have exactly same problem. When the user form is submitted, data is saved but the form goes blank and i see this error. Everything worked BEFORE i switched to collection2-core 2 etc